# synchronized problem related to calibration

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All.

I Am a rookie in Ros, I am using ros fuerte and a monocular camera. My
lapto's camera.

I want to know how many things I need to setup to make a retification image with image_proc package.

I already setup a launch file, I attached

But when I ran the image_view to display the image rectify, I got nothing.
And when I ran the image_view to display the image mono, it works.

So I want to know what things I have to setup to do a rectification image.
And what thing I did wrong.

I attached the rxgraph output, my launch file and my camera parameters

Besides I have a warning:

[image_transport] Topics '/Dava/image_mono' and '/Dava/gscam/camera_info' do not appear to be synchronized. In the last 10s:
Image messages received:      80
CameraInfo messages received: 80
Synchronized pairs:           0

I will appreciate any respond . Thank you

[image: image description]

[image: image description]

[Output.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/13806688904420701.png)

[Test_Launch.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/13804128631802391.png)

you can download the launch file to this link:
https://mega.co.nz/#!fohxhQYY!RIuUOVuf1mL8Nn_erxkrujVt8zUmsLn-4_kP2YokMxc

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/84611/synchronized-problem-related-to-calibration/) by [Dava2788](https://answers.ros.org/users/3554/dava2788/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2013-09-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2013-09-30**:
What is the output of `rosconsole` when you start your launch file?

**Comment by [Dava2788](https://answers.ros.org/users/3554/dava2788/) on 2013-10-01**:
I just uploaded

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2013-10-06**:
Apparently the camera information is not correctly synchronized, this may be a bug of gscam. Also, camera information may be incorrect and rejected, hence the lack of data. Can you copy and paste in your original question two or three outputs of this topic?

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2013-10-07**:
@Thomas this is a bug from the old (svn) version of gscam, and has been fixed for months in the released version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The code you are using is out of date. The sync bug has been fixed in the current released versions of gscam (0.1.1), the source versions of which can be found here: https://github.com/ros-drivers/gscam

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2013-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dava2788](https://answers.ros.org/users/3554/dava2788/) on 2013-10-07**:
Thank you. I will download it.
Final question,  one of these version works in ROS FUERTE, right?

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2013-10-07**:
Yes, gscam 0.1.1 can be built in a rosbuild-based workspace.

**Comment by [Dava2788](https://answers.ros.org/users/3554/dava2788/) on 2013-10-07**:
Thank you, jbohren.

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2013-10-08**:
@Dava2788 so did it work?

**Comment by [Dava2788](https://answers.ros.org/users/3554/dava2788/) on 2013-10-08**:
I'm going to test it this afternoon. I will let you know.

**Comment by [Dava2788](https://answers.ros.org/users/3554/dava2788/) on 2013-10-08**:
@Jbohren, thanks it work, I could see the rectify image. But I just have another problem, when I tried to Subscribed that topic (Image_rect) to another node (Viso2). It show again the sync msg (warning message). I don't know if I'm doing something wrong with the configuration with viso2 or is gscam

**Comment by [Dava2788](https://answers.ros.org/users/3554/dava2788/) on 2013-10-08**:
I going to close this question and open a new one if I stil have this issue. Thanks @jbohren.